# Export and publish all types and interfaces in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to publish a typescript library. It is not clear to me how to expose all the types and interfaces. Here is my setup:

```
mylib
  ├──src
  │  ├──types
  |  |  └──mytypes.ts
  │  └──index.ts
  ├──package.json
  └──tsconfig.json
```

```typescript
//index.ts

import {MyInterface} from './types/mytypes.ts';

const my_main_name = {
  myfunc: function(param1:MyInterface):void{
    console.log(param1.a);
  }
}
```

```typescript
//mytypes.ts

export interface MyInterface {
  a:string
}
```

I am generating declaration files by setting `tsconfig.json` param `"declaration":"true"`.

Now I want to use this libraries as dependency of another one.

```
mylib
yrlib
  ├──src
  │  └──index.ts
  ├──package.json
  └──tsconfig.json
```

```json
//yrlib/package.json
{
 ...
 "dependencies":{
    "mylib":"file:../mylib/"
  }
}
```

```typescript
//yrlib/src/index.ts

import * as mylib from 'mylib';

let a:mylib.MyInterface = ...
      // ~~ Namespace has no export member for MyInterface
```

I get autocomplete for `mylib` because it is exported.

My question is how can I see all the types and interfaces of `mylib` module inside `yrlib`?

Since they can be hundreds and in all different files and folders.

Should I export all of them one by one? What is the best practice?
Is there a way to export all types at once?

And how `"typying":"dist/index.d.ts"` in `package.json` fits in all this? Should be all the types in one file? Why Typescript doesn't generate this file?

Should I use a namespace that contain everything? I cannot find a full explanation on this topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently faced the same problem and the only way I found in order to publish your *Type-Space code* (e.g.: types, interfaces) together with your *Value-Space code* (e.g.: function, classes, variables) is to export a `namespace` that contains everything.

Another odd thing is that in order to export into a `namespace` something imported, the syntax is:

```typescript
import * as mymod from './mymod';
import * as mytypes from './mytypes';

export namespace mylib {
  export import mod = mymod;
  export import types = mytypes;
}
```

With the `export import` syntax.

Unfortunately this in my eslinter will resolve in a warning/error since apparently it reads `mod` and `types` as `unused-vars`.

I don't understand why there is no a full explanation for this topic in the documentation.